# Refreshing a Partialview inside a DIV with jquery and Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my partial view:

```
@model UADDPortal.ViewModels.DatabaseInfoViewModel

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<tr>
    <td><h5> Status:  @Model.CurrentStatus </h5> </td>
    <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="RefreshResourceStatus@(Model.CheckoutID)" id="RefreshResourceStatus@(Model.CheckoutID)" value="Refresh" /></td>
</tr>
```

This is my Main page:

```
<div id="ResourceStatus@(item.CheckoutID)"> 
  @Html.Partial("ResourceStatus", item)
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#RefreshResourceStatus@(item.CheckoutID)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // stop the links default behavior
        $('#ResourceStatus@(item.CheckoutID)').load('/Home/GetCurrentStatus/@(item.CheckoutID)');
    });
});
</script>
```

And finally, this is my ajax method inside my main MVC controller:

```
    #region ajax calls
    public PartialViewResult GetCurrentStatus(string Id)
    {
        var viewModel = new DatabaseInfoViewModel(null);
        viewModel.CheckoutID = Convert.ToInt32(Id);
        viewModel.CurrentStatus = viewModel.GetCurrentStatus(Convert.ToInt32(Id));

        return PartialView("ResourceStatus", viewModel);
    }

    #endregion ajax calls
```

The problem is that the refresh button generated in the DIV section, seems to work randomly...sometimes works...most of the time doesn't do anything....I cant figure out why....

Comment: make sure the content is not getting cached.

Comment: do you have more than one item?

Comment: I solved the "only works once" issue, by adding this to the jscript function: $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

Comment: Murali: yes.....this div is generated inside a foreach loop....you can have N amount of these div sections with their own jscript function each......... I fixed the cache problem with $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });, but I still experience a weird behavior.... The first click on the button loads correctly....the second click refreshs the entire page (no idea why)......the third one loads correctly....the fourth refresh everything.....and so on...

Comment: You can load it using `$.post()` so it will not be cached. Also you can move the checkoutid to `data-*` attribute and keep code simple. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one item, better use `data-*` attribute for checkoutid population.

```
@model UADDPortal.ViewModels.DatabaseInfoViewModel

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<tr>
    <td><h5> Status:  @Model.CurrentStatus </h5> </td>
    <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-checkout" 
         data-chekout-id="@(Model.CheckoutID)" value="Refresh" /></td>
</tr>
```

Then

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.btn-checkout').click(function(e){

      var checkoutId=$(this).data("chekout-id");
      var targetDiv='#ResourceStatus'+checkoutId;

      $.post('url',{Id:checkoutId},function(result){

        $(targetDiv).html(result);

       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Fede in the comments on his question

```
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

solved the issue for me.